# Assign variable to user input in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view,the user needs input some data using collection_select.

I know the data can be accessed using `params[]` in the controller.

But how do I access the value the user right after has selected a value?

This is what I am trying to do(doesnt work):

```
<%= f.collection_select :photo_type, Upload::PHOTOTYPE, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => false, :id => "phototype"%>
<%= f.hidden_field :photo_id, :value => Photo.find_by_type(params[:photo_type]).id %>
```

My question is how do I access the `:photo_type` in the `collection_select`?

**EDIT**

I have tried using jQuery but I don't know how to export the js variable to the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#phototype").change(function() {
        var phototype = $('#phototype').val()
    });
 </script>
```

**UPDATE**

I have two tables in my database:

Table 1: `photos`

1. id
2. photo_type_id (refer to `id` in the `photo_types` table)

Table 2: `photo_types`

1. id
2. photo_type

User can select photo type from the drop down menu, and I want to find the `photo_type_id` in the `photo_types` table by the user input and then insert the `photo_type_id` into the `photos` table

According to codeit, I changed my controller like this:

```
def create
    @photo = photo.new(params[:photo])
    photo_type_id = PhotoType.find_by_type(params[:photo_type]).id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: You need some javascript here, a function triggered on change of your collection_select that will update the value of the photo_id hidden_field.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, yes I tried it, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `hidden_field` to send value to next action. Why don't you do the same in controller action:

```
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.photo_type_id = PhotoType.find_by_type(params[:photo][:photo_type]).id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View:

```
  <%= f.collection_select :photo_type, Upload::PHOTOTYPE, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => false, :id => "phototype"%>
```

**Suggestion**: Standard practice is avoiding queries in views.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I put this in the controller, doesn't it mean I have to submit the form in order to the get id?

Comment: You need to submit the form and find `id` there. I am not getting why are you using `hidden_field` when u don't want to submit form.

Comment: I want to insert the value of `photo_id` into the `photos` table after submitting the form, but the problem is: I have to find the id in another table by `photo_type`.

Comment: You can do it in controller after submitting form. And I don't understand why you do want to put `photo_id` in same table(`photos`)

Comment: Then that should be `photo_id = PhotoType.find_by_type(params[:photo_type]).id`. You can do it in controller after form submit. Could you post controller where u want to add `photo_type_id` to `photos`??

Comment: Updated with the new controller. However, I think I kinda mislead you by the question. What I am trying to do here is: BEFORE submitting the form, I let user select the photo type from the drop down menu, then I grab this photo type and looking for its `id` in the `photo_types` table, then I grab this `id` and at last I submit this form and insert the `id` into the `photos` table.

Comment: @JohnPowel you don't need to grab `photo_type_id` in view. You can do it in controller. See the edited answer.

Comment: @JohnPowel You don't need that `hidden_field`.. its of no use when you do it in controller.

Comment: Whats your `params` in log??

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I mistyped `params[:photo][:photo_type]` by `params[:photo_type]`, it works! thank you so much!!